# Pie charts in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm using the code below to draw some graphs and combine them. When I execute the entire file I get the error:

> "Invalid Syntax r(198)".

And the code stops at the code segment below.  However, when I run the code segment separately the program works without a flaw.  Can you please help me understand what's causing this issue?

```
*pie chart 
foreach i in "SPA" "EPD"{
    graph pie  billed_amount if type== "`i'", over(service_id) saving(gg`i',replace) 
    local gg `gg' "gg`i'"
}
local gg: subinstr local gg "ggSPA" `""ggSPA""'
gr combine `gg'
graph export "C\provider.png", as(png) replace
graph drop _all
```

Comment: Anyone searching for "invalid sy[n]tax" would be unlikely to find this question helpful, so I've edited the title.

Answer (score 1):

Without any context -- whether the code before this that makes a difference -- or a dataset to use -- how can we tell? The problem lacks a minimal complete verifiable example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for this and future questions.

That said, this seems to be a very roundabout way to get two pie charts side-by-side. That doesn't require a loop and it doesn't require `graph combine`.

```
graph pie billed_amount if inlist(type, "SPA", "EPD"), over(service_id) by(type) 
graph export "C\provider.png", as(png) replace
```

Whether you want to drop all graphs afterwards is quite immaterial to the problem posed.